# Angular JS News Feed doesn't auto update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a news feed page in angular JS. Whenever a change in application by user it should be updated on news page. I am showing the changes in news feed page. But problem when i refresh the page it shows the change. I have to show the changes without refreshing the page. I am loading data from http url.

So far i tried 
html code:

```
<div> ng-controller="TopListCtrl"
  <div class="cb-feed-wrapper bradius5" ng-repeat="post in posts">

<h3>{{ post.userId}}</h3>
<p> {{post.change}} </p><p> Created On : {{ post.createdOn }} | Updated On : {{ post.updatedOn }} </p><p Time: {{ post.dateTime }}</p>
</div></div>
```

Controller Code:

```
function TopListCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout) {
 $scope.refreshInterval = 1;
$http({
      url: '/zzzz/v1/zzzz/all?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
      method: "GET"

  }).success(function (data) {
          $scope.posts = data; 

      }).error(function (data) {
       });
$timeout(function() { 
    $scope.refreshInterval * 5;
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to poll for updates?  You're never making a call after the initial page load (your `$timeout` simple updates a refreshInterval var that isn't used to schedule another `$http` call.  You have `post` in your template and `posts` in your controller.  I'm assuming you skipped an `ng-repeat` container?

Comment: Can you provide any sample code??

Comment: @kevin stone: Any reference link or sample program

Answer (score 5):

Your controller should look like this:

```
function TopListCtrl($scope, $http, $interval) {
  $scope.refreshInterval = 5; // For every 5 sec

  // Create a function as we will reuse this code
  function refresh() {
    $http({
      url: '/lexaserver/v1/audit/all?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
      method: "GET"

    }).success(function (data) {
      $scope.posts = data; 

    }).error(function (data) {
      console.log('Error');
    });
  }

  refresh(); // We call the function on initialization to load the feed.

  // $interval runs the given function every X millisec (2nd arg)
  $interval(function() { 
    refresh();
  }, $scope.refreshInterval * 1000); // the refresh interval must be in millisec
}
```

But I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with `$scope.refreshInterval`.

Comment: I am showing data in my page correctly. But page should auto update at particular interval of time

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to change the `$timeout` dependency to `$interval` in the first line.

Comment: You need `$interval`. Update your first line as I updated my answer.

Comment: Error: Unknown provider: $intervalProvider <- $interval this is the error i get often

Comment: It seems that `$interval` has been added in Angular 1.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some polling mechanism to make repeated `http` calls, on set time interval if you want to refresh data again (which you are not doing). See a example fiddle here http://plnkr.co/edit/iMmhXTYweN4IrRrrpvMq?p=preview

Comment: I tried with this sample but it hits server but unable to set response on get back

Comment: This is to give you an idea. What exactly did you try. And what do you mean when you say unable to set response on get back.

Comment: After hitting poller function data cannot be set on scope$scope.data = Poller.data;